# Can I uninstall amdgpu-install after using it?

Tags: amdgpu

I installed it from amd website and did sudo apt install ./amdgpu-install_whatever.deb
So can I sudo apt remove amdgpu-install or whatever on it after installing it?
k um yeah, that's all I was asking....

Comment: Yes, of course you could uninstall the package using `apt remove`

Comment: Are you asking if a manually downloaded deb package installed with the new apt syntax (as quoted in your question) can be uninstalled using the generic `sudo apt remove package` syntax? Or just if you can remove this particular software?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-installing.html#uninstalling-the-amdgpu-stack), Of course!
 You can remove these package by typing in the following terminal:
`$ amdgpu-uninstall`

Take advice of this: You are removing the entire driver utilities.